# I have used a resource dictionary for adding a little green square

Tags: wpf, dictionary, resources, runtime, tabitem

I have added a resource dictionary for my tabcontrol to use. Each tabitem has a little box on the right   which is defined in the resource dictionary.

I would like to change the colour based on a checkbox in each tabitem. Currently if I do this in code behind all tabitems are changing colour

LinearGradientBrush lgbrush = (LinearGradientBrush)(this.FindResource("TabItemSideBackground"));
                    lgbrush.GradientStops[0].Color = Colors.AntiqueWhite;
                    lgbrush.GradientStops[1].Color = Colors.Red;
                    lgbrush.GradientStops[2].Color = Colors.OrangeRed;

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Triggers.  In the TabItem DataTemplate or style, you can add triggers that handle specific values on properties, and perform property setting.  Take a look at the [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) class page at MSDN.

## A Short Example

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SomeObject, Path=SomeProperty}" Value="MakeItRed">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MyRedBrush}" />
      </DataTrigger>    
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```